# Can't manage to make page to specific route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Here is the app component:

```
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="flex  border-2 border-grey flex-col max-w-4xl min-h-screen mx-auto">
        <Navigation />
        <MainContainer>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route>
              <CreateBlog path="/create" />
            </Route>
            <Route>
              <FullBlogDetails path="/blogs/:id" />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </MainContainer>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

The problem is that each time I click a blog, it redirects me to `"/create"`, instead of `"/blogs/:id"`.

Here is the `Link` that does the navigation:

```
<Link
  to={`/blogs/${id}`}
  key={id}
  className="p-4 flex border-2 border-grey-200 items-center hover:shadow-lg my-6"
>
  <div>
    <img className="h-20" src={picture} />
    <p className="">
      Written by{" "}
      <span className="text-rose-500 font-bold text-lg">
        {firstName + " " + lastName}
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <p className="font-bold">"{title}..."</p>
</Link>
```

---

The weird part is that if I swap the `"/create"` `Route` with `"/blogs/:id"` `Route`, making it third, the app only shows the `"/blogs/:id"` and then `"/create"` doesn't show now. Basically the third route doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've incorrectly placed the `path` prop for the routes on the routed component instead of the `Route` component. The `Switch` component only renders the first matching `Route` or `Redirect` and so a `Route` sans the `path` prop will *always* match. Since the route for both `"/create"` and `"/blogs/:id"` is missing the `path` prop it makes sense that swapping their order and trying to navigate to the second still matches and renders the first.

Move the `path` prop to the `Route` component. I suggest also ordering the routes in inverse order of path specificity so ***more*** specific paths are rendered before ***less*** specific paths. This generally omits the need to specify the `exact` prop.

Example:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="flex  border-2 border-grey flex-col max-w-4xl min-h-screen mx-auto">
    <Navigation />
    <MainContainer>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/create">    // <-- path on route
          <CreateBlog />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/blogs/:id"> // <-- path on route
          <FullBlogDetails />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">          // <-- path on route
          <Home />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </MainContainer>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```